# Permisson denied installation to USB flash

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I'm trying to use basic command utilites to write ISO to USB flash. I'm writing:

```
sudo cat path/to/archlinux-version-x86_64.iso > /dev/disk/by-id/usb-My_flash_drive
```

but I have response:

```
zsh: permission denied: /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic_Mass_Storage_C5BB4803F4D97884-0:0
```

Maybe I need to give roots for writing to this device?

**Update.** Solved with:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=archlinux-2023.07.01-x86_64.iso of=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic_Mass_Storage_C5BB4803F4D97884-0:0 conv=fsync oflag=direct status=progress
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a command line like:

```
sudo cat path/to/archlinux-version-x86_64.iso > /dev/disk/by-id/usb-My_flash_drive
```

the shell will attempt to set up the redirection just before starting to execute the actual command. As a result, only the `cat path/to/archlinux-version-x86_64.iso` part will be affected by `sudo`; this is probably not what you intended. You need `sudo` for the writing into a device, not necessarily for reading a regular file (unless you don't have normal access to that file).

One way to rearrange this command to work with `sudo` and redirection would be:

```
cat path/to/archlinux-version-x86_64.iso | sudo tee /dev/disk/by-id/usb-My_flash_drive >/dev/null
```

Here, the shell will first set up the pipeline between the two commands and the redirection of the resulting output before starting the two commands *in parallel*. The `tee /dev/disk/by-id/usb-My_flash_drive` will run with root privileges; it will pass one copy of its input to the flash drive and another to standard output. The redirection set up by the shell will run as your regular user account, and will pass the standard output of `tee` to `/dev/null`, which requires no special privileges to do.

The above re-arrangement is similar to your original command line, but it could be called a "useless use of `cat`" since you could just as well do it with no pipe at all, as long as you can read the `.iso` file as a regular user:

```
sudo tee /dev/disk/by-id/usb-My_flash_drive < path/to/archlinux-version-x86_64.iso > /dev/null
```